# Interface clarification

Tags: java

One more clarification about interfaces. Suppose, there is a class:

```
public interface Foo {

    public static final String doSmth();

    public static String doSmth2();

    public final String doSmth3();

    public String doSmth4();

    public abstract String doSmth5();

}
```

1) Can I write `abstract` in method head in interfaces?

2) Can I omit words `static`, `public`, and `final` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such interface. You'll get a compilererror. 1.) `final` methods can't be overriden. But you'll have to implement them because they are part of the interface. 2.) `static` methods can't be overriden. And due to this aren't allowed in interfaces (atleast not without methodbody). The accessmodifiers can be left out. But keep in mind, that methods without accessmodifier are packagelocal!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Methods are `abstract` by default in interfaces.
2. You can never omit `static`, `public` is just like in any other class, and you cannot have `final` methods in an interface.

And just so you know, the code of yours won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in an interfaces are public static and final implicitely.
You can't create static methods in interfaces.
the final methods cannot be overrides, if a method in interface is final it cannot be override by any class so it has no sense of using final.